# Keras : ValueError Input 0 of layer "Conv1_pad" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=1

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to use the teachable machine keras .h5 model using Python w/ Flask, But after uploading the image from the flask frontend and going through the keras model, I don't get a prediction instead I receive this ValueError :

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model2" "  f"(typeFunctional).

Input 0 of layer "Conv1_pad" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)

Call arguments received by layer "model2" "  f"(type Functional):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

app.py
**(labels.txt contains 2 predictions 0 : hi 1: bye )**

```
#Model
model = load_model(MODEL_PATH, compile=False)
#Labels here
class_names = open('labels.txt', 'r').readlines()
data = [0]
def model_predict(img_path, model, class_names):
    global data # Data made global so it can be accessed by upload function
    data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    
    img = image.load_img(img_path).convert('RGB')
    size = (224, 224)
    image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    image_array = np.asarray(image)  #conversion of the image to an array

    normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1 
    data[0] = normalized_image_array
    return data


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    # Main page code removed for shortening


@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']

        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(
            basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)
        #PREDICTION MADE HERE
        preds = model.predict(data)  #Error in this Code Block
        index = np.argmax(preds)
        class_name = class_names[index] #Assigning of class-name to the prediction index
        result = str(class_name, end = '')

        return result
    return None
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated as this is my first time working with Keras, Thanks :)